# how to get index of an element from bean type array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, for-loop, arraylist

I want to get indexOf a first name from ArrayList.

Here is my bean class

```
public class BeanClass {
static String firstname;
String lastname;
int rollno;

public BeanClass(String firstname, String lastname, int rollno) {
    super();
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.rollno = rollno;
}
```

and here is Main Activity

```
public class MainClass {

    static ArrayList<BeanClass>arraylist=new ArrayList<>();
    static String firstname[]={"kshitij","ravi","prakash","sunil"};
    staticString lastname[]={"singh","sharma","verma","tiwari"};
    staticint rollno[]={1,2,3,4};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < firstname.length; i++) {
            BeanClass bean=new BeanClass(firstname[i],lastname[i],rollno[i]);
            arraylist.add(bean);
        }
         System.out.println(arraylist.indexOf("kshitij"));
    }
}
```

Comment: To do it the way you want, the ArrayList should have String as generic argument. You'll have to build you own function that iterates over the list, checking object by object if firstname is the one you passed as argument.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get index of following name you want to declare a variable

`int index = 0`;

and replace this line `System.out.println(arraylist.indexOf("kshitij"));` with this code

```
for (BeanClass bean: arraylist) {
    if (bean.firstname.equals("kshitij")) {           
        System.out.println("Index is " + index);
        break;
    }
    index++
}
```

its return index of your first name where it store. i assume index start from 0

Comment: You need to break, when you find the match

Comment: yes we can break but it's print index when the condition is true otherwise is skip to print it

Comment: `yes we can break but it's print index when the condition is true otherwise is skip to print it`, Your statement doesn't make anysense..

Comment: its get index only when its condition true (bean.firstname.equals("kshitij")) else its not print index

Answer (score 1):

Note that your `ArrayList` contains `BeanClass`. It's value is not `"kshitij"`, but one of variable of your `BeanClass`.

You have to declare an `index` variable, loop `ArrayList` through and find your `index` out:

```
int index = 0; // Index variable
for (BeanClass bean: arraylist) {
    if (bean.firstname.equals("kshitij")) {
        System.out.println(index);
        break;
    } 
    index++;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

By the way, in the `BeanClass` your variable `firstname` should be not `static`, or all of instances will have the `firstname` same is then searching it by a firstname loses a sence.

So redefine your `BeanClass` to:

```
public class BeanClass {
   String firstname;
   String lastname;
   int rollno;

   // ...
}
```

Comment: You need to break, when you find the match

Comment: Right, no need to loop more. Thanks for a hint.

Comment: Also, OP is looking for index, not the value.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here:[Java ArrayList IndexOf - Finding Object Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519019/java-arraylist-indexof-finding-object-index)

You should build your own `equals` method to be able to use `indexOf`.
Also, you will need to pass an object of `BeanClass` to `indexOf`

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof BeanClass)) return false;
    BeanClass other = (BeanClass) o;
    return (this.firstname == other.firstname && this.lastname == other.lastname );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IntStream` in Java 8 as follows:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
    .filter(i -> arrayList.get(i).firstname.equals("kshiij"))
    .findFirst()
    .getAsInt();
```

Remember, `getAsInt` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if a matching element is not contained in the list. Don't forget to catch it.